# CSS gradient with filters on background-image

Tags: html, css

I have problem with applying the gradient filter on my image. I want gradient beginning from black to full transparent from top to bottom and from bottom to top. I have definied css for div and with single color (`background-color`) works, but with image(`background-image`) it won't.

My style definition is:

```
#some_id{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(8%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))),
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(8%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
    -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */

background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
    -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
    linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 8%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */ 

background-image: url('../images/tla/tlo1.jpg');

}
```

Can You help me?

Comment: your gradient is a `background-image`. You override the gradient with the last line of your css.

Comment: But when I add it after coma to previous definitions it still won't work

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/8jqM8/

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I don't why it didn't work before :)